# Populating JTextFields with object data taken from selected comboBox item

Tags: java, swing

I'll try to explain the problem as best i can.

Basically what I have is a system that takes in customer data (Customer is an object) and then adds it to an array. I have that working no problems. What I'm trying to get working is that I also have an option that should enable the user to edit a customers details. The way I'm trying to implement this is; in a separate GUI, I have a comboBox which will be populated with all of the customers first names that are currently in the arrayList. This also works.

Here is my problem - what I want to happen is that when one of the customers first names is chosen from the comboBox, it should find that object, and then fill out the JTextFields with its respective data, e.g. that customers first name should pop into the first name textField and his second name into the second name TextField etc..

I cant figure out this problem so any help is appreciated!

This is only one of a few classes, the rest of which work.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.text.MaskFormatter;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import java.awt.SystemColor;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;

import javax.swing.UIManager;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFormattedTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;

public class editCustomers extends JFrame {

private JPanel contentPane;
private JTextField textField;
private JTextField textField_1;
private JTextField textField_2;
private JTextField textField_3;
ArrayList<Customers> customerList;
private MaskFormatter mask = null;


/**
 * Create the frame.
 */
public editCustomers(ArrayList<Customers> aList) {
    customerList = aList;
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 700, 600);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
    setContentPane(contentPane);

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    contentPane.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(6, 0, 0, 0));

    JPanel panel_12 = new JPanel();
    panel.add(panel_12);
    panel_12.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));

    JLabel lblSelectACustomer = new JLabel("Select a Customer to Edit");
    panel_12.add(lblSelectACustomer, BorderLayout.WEST);

    JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox();
    //comboBox.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel());
    for (Customers temp : customerList) {
        comboBox.addItem(temp.getfName());
        }
    panel_12.add(comboBox, BorderLayout.EAST);



    JPanel panel_3 = new JPanel();
    panel.add(panel_3);
    panel_3.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));

    JLabel lbl1 = new JLabel("Edit Customers First Name");
    lbl1.setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.TOP);
    Dimension d = lbl1.getPreferredSize();
    lbl1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(d.width + 50, d.height));
    panel_3.add(lbl1, BorderLayout.WEST);

    JPanel panel_8 = new JPanel();
    panel_3.add(panel_8, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    textField = new JTextField();
    panel_8.add(textField);
    textField.setColumns(30);

    JPanel panel_4 = new JPanel();
    panel.add(panel_4);
    panel_4.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));

    JLabel lbl2 = new JLabel("Edit Customers Second Name");
    lbl2.setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.TOP);
    lbl2.getPreferredSize();
    lbl2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(d.width + 50, d.height));
    panel_4.add(lbl2, BorderLayout.WEST);

    JPanel panel_9 = new JPanel();
    panel_4.add(panel_9, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    textField_1 = new JTextField();
    panel_9.add(textField_1);
    textField_1.setColumns(30);

    JPanel panel_5 = new JPanel();
    panel.add(panel_5);
    panel_5.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));

    JLabel lbl3 = new JLabel("Edit Customers Address");
    lbl3.setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.TOP);
    lbl3.getPreferredSize();
    lbl3.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(d.width + 50, d.height));
    panel_5.add(lbl3, BorderLayout.WEST);

    JPanel panel_10 = new JPanel();
    panel_5.add(panel_10, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    textField_2 = new JTextField();
    panel_10.add(textField_2);
    textField_2.setColumns(30);

    JPanel panel_6 = new JPanel();
    panel.add(panel_6);
    panel_6.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));

    JLabel lbl4 = new JLabel("Edit Customers Date of Birth");
    lbl4.setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.TOP);
    lbl4.getPreferredSize();
    lbl4.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(d.width + 50, d.height));
    panel_6.add(lbl4, BorderLayout.WEST);

    JPanel panel_11 = new JPanel();
    panel_6.add(panel_11, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    textField_3 = new JTextField();
    try {
        mask = new MaskFormatter("##/##/####");
        mask.setPlaceholderCharacter(' ');
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }       
    JFormattedTextField textField_3 = new JFormattedTextField(mask);
    textField_3.setText("dd/mm/yyyy");
    panel_11.add(textField_3);
    textField_3.setColumns(30);

    JPanel panel_2 = new JPanel();
    panel.add(panel_2);
    panel_2.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));

    JPanel panel_7 = new JPanel();
    panel_2.add(panel_7, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    JButton btnConfirm = new JButton("Confirm");
    btnConfirm.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        }
    });
    panel_7.add(btnConfirm);

    JButton btnCancel = new JButton("Cancel");
    btnCancel.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            dispose();
        }
    });
    panel_7.add(btnCancel);

    JPanel panel_1 = new JPanel();
    panel_1.setBackground(SystemColor.activeCaption);
    contentPane.add(panel_1, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    JLabel lblEditACurrent = new JLabel("Edit a Current Customer");
    lblEditACurrent.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    lblEditACurrent.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 19));
          lblEditACurrent.setBackground(UIManager.getColor("InternalFrame.activeTitleBackground"));
    panel_1.add(lblEditACurrent);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                editCustomers frame = new editCustomers(new ArrayList<Customers>());
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

}
```

Comment: I would suggest having a close look at [How to Use Combo Boxes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html) and [How to Write an Action Listener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html) which should give you the basic information you need to complete your task

Comment: you will want to create a function definition like public Customer FindCustomer(String firstName) and then inside that function you loop through the customerList list until you find the Customer whose first name matches the parameter given and return that Customer who matches. Once you have that function the rest should be straight forward.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this ....
Change line 63 - 67 as following. Put the customers into the combobox instead of just names.

```
JComboBox<Customer> comboBox = new JComboBox<>();
//comboBox.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel());
for (Customers temp : customerList) {
    comboBox.addItem(temp);
}
```

Then implement an ActionListener for the combobox as following.

```
comboBox.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        Customer customer = comboBox.getSelectedItem();
        // Use the above customer object's fields to populate your text fields

    }
});
```